# Copying an element of a volatile ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

Say I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private volatile ArrayList<ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>> arraylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>>();

    // ...code...

    public void set(ArrayList<ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>> newArraylist)
    {
        arraylist = newArraylist;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyImmutableClass> get(int i)
    {
        return new ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>(arraylist.get(i));
    }
}
```

I realize that by making `arraylist` volatile, I'm not actually making its contents volatile as well - I'm only making the reference to the `ArrayList<ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>>` object volatile. But one thing I can't quite wrap my head around, is what would happen if `set()` were to change `arraylist`'s reference mid way through `get()` constructing its `new ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>`?

My gut says it would be fine - the reference passed to the ArrayList's copy constructor by `arraylist.get(i)` would not be changed, only the reference held by `arraylist` would be changed by `set()` - but I haven't been able to find a definite answer one way or another.

Comment: What are you afraid could happen?

Comment: What you've done here is actually part of the general principle behind [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: @Radiodef How so? There isn't any writing here.

Comment: @shmosel But the volatile read of the array list ensures a correct read of its contents *if* the writes to its contents occurred before the volatile reference assignment. OP's code isn't thread-safe but that's the general principle behind a data structure such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: @Radiodef Why isn't this code thread-safe?

Comment: @lexicore Somebody can call `set` and then modify the contents of the list they pass in after the volatile assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But one thing I can't quite wrap my head around, is what would happen if set() were to change arraylist's reference mid way through get() constructing its new ArrayList?

After `arraylist.get(i)` is called and the resulting list is passed to `new ArrayList<MyImmutableClass>`, changing `arraylist` has no influence on that list.  Changing the value of the variable can not influence results of operation performed on the old value. And `volatile` has actually nothing to do with it.